Performance Insights Panel not visible in devtools after building it locally
I have built chrome devtools-frontend locally.
Ref: https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/
I am unable to view the performance insights panel, I have tried checking it under More tools. And have also tried searching for it with Cmd+shift+p.
ive tried building multiple devtools versions as well they are 6312, 5481, 5005
Not able to view in any of them. Am i missing some setting in devtools where i can enable this? Or is there some param or argument needed while building this?
Any insights around this would be helpful (pun intended)
